# How can I input an anchor link into a section of a theme on Shopify?

Tags: html, shopify

I understand that inputting  should mark an anchor on a given page but I don't know how to identify the template for sections on the home page. I know that I can modify the homepage in the template "index.liquid" but I don't know to edit the specific sections uploaded to the homepage. I have no coding experience so any guidance on how to identify the liquid file from which the section of a page can be modified will be a huge help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code with your problem. Read [shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to StackOverflow!

You're right that the `index.liquid` is going to be where the "homepage" lives, but all the content that is added to that will be added from the Customize editor.

As far as where to access the sections specifically... if your theme has sections enabled -- which I'll assume that it does -- there should be a folder labeled **Sections** with all possibilities available in your sidebar. It would be under **Templates** and above **Snippets**.

Then just look for the **{section}.liquid** that you have in question -- it might take some Sherlock Holmes investigation to find the specific one you want -- and add the anchor tag that you want to add.

Some examples of some names of liquid files that you'd find on the homepage are as follows:

```
featured-blog.liquid
featured-product.liquid
slideshow.liquid
```

If you have any further questions please feel free to ask and expand on what it is you need - but I just wanted to help point you in the right direction.

Especially if this is your first time reaching out for help on StackOverflow!